# Three.js. Why does Spotlight not allow the near/far to be reset?

Tags: three.js

I created a spotlight thusly:

```
let spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight( color, intensity );

spotLight.castShadow = true;

spotLight.shadow.mapSize.width = shadowSize;
spotLight.shadow.mapSize.height = shadowSize;
spotLight.shadow.camera.near = near;
spotLight.shadow.camera.far = far;
```

Works fine. In then tried to change the `near` and `far`:

```
this.spotLight.shadow.camera.near = near;
this.spotLight.shadow.camera.far = far;

this.spotLight.shadow.update(this.spotLight);
```

Nothing happens. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

If you change a camera's constructor parameters, you need to update the camera's projection matrix. This is true for a shadow camera, too.

```
light.shadow.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
```

three.js r.103

Comment: Yes, spotLight.shadow.update(this.spotLight) calls updateProjectionMatrix() internally. It has no effect, though.

Comment: `shadow.update()` is called every frame. Given your code fragments, it is hard to know what you have done, or are doing. Make sure `.shadow` is a `SpotLightShadow`, and not a `LightShadow`. Step though with the debugger, and you should be able to see what is going on.

Comment: Here is my spotlight/dropshadow class: https://gist.github.com/turner/5db8957fe0a3daa927b6fcf073517b71

Comment: Here is the relevant code that instantiates and updates the class: https://gist.github.com/turner/443e44feb30077d566f71811e531b3f2